# Meaning of "Routine" in "Routine imaging of the brain is not required to diagnose BH4Ds"

Tags: terminology, metabolism, mri

From [Consensus guideline for the diagnosis and treatment of tetrahydrobiopterin (BH4) deficiencies](https://ojrd.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s13023-020-01379-8)

> Recommendation #27 (conditional): **Routine imaging** of the brain is not required to diagnose BH4Ds.

Can we rephrase **routine** as "**typically**" thus:

> **Typically**, imaging of the brain is not required to diagnose BH4Ds.

Or is there some other meaning of the word **routine** here?

Could it mean "**typical methods of scanning** are useless in diagnosing BH4Ds, but maybe some advanced techniques are better, but thus far we don't know"?

Comment: It doesn't mean more than it says. It just says imaging routinely (ie, without a reason for suspicion) isn't necessary. I think your first suggestion of saying, "Typically, ..." would be a reasonable translation. But I also think this question would be a better fit on English Language and Usage.SE. It's really just a language question and doesn't require medical knowledge.

Comment: @CareyGregory - thank you! I thought that there might be some aspects of meaning that could be missed by users on language-related sites.